# Adaptec ASR-6805T can create raid from ssd only?

Tags: raid, ssd, hardware-raid, adaptec

I'm about to move my Proxmox home server from NAS to RAID 10. I'm a hardware RAID fan, so I chose a solution among inexpensive old controllers. In the course of studying budget solutions for the home, the choice fell on the "Adaptec ASR-6805T (BBU) 512 MB".

I came across some controversial information on the net, saying that it will only accept HDD or HDD + SSD hybrid. Is it possible to use an SSD with this RAID controller without problems?
What problems can I face?

Comment: Have you try to contact manufacturer and ask about pure SSD run?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Do you think this is a good idea? I will try.

ps I did not do this because I had experience with other manufacturers. As a rule, they do not give information about outdated and unsupported equipment, but refer to the documentation that I have already seen.

Comment: You can try, sometime you can get the answer :) Other way (if you have time and budget) is to buy small (but unused) SSD drives and make tests for the reliability and use cases you read about.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for the answer. And what inexpensive controller for 6 SSD drives would you recommend?
Interested in the presence of raid 10 and stability

Comment: For hardware recommendation please ask your question here: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/